# How to keep an element from splitting into two paths

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, data-visualization

Here's the [codePen](http://codepen.io/mcKrack/pen/MyxNez?editors=0010) i've been working on. It will be best to refer to this for the full code, don't want to clutter the post with it all.

I'm having a problem with the inner circle (the grey circle inside the donut, with the number 644 on top).

Problem is, the inner circle is being split into two parts (two paths), and I can't figure out why (you can also see where the two parts meet, if you look close enough).

I tried creating two variables with different data that I then passed through into the inner circle (innerPie) — see code below.

Why is the circle within my donut chart getting separated into two parts? 
How can I just make a whole circle?

```js
// this is for the donut chart
     var pie = d3.layout.pie()
        .sort(null)
        .value(function(d) { return d.region; });

    // new variable i created just for the inner circle
    var innerPie = d3.layout.pie()
        .sort(null)
        .value(function(d) { return d.toursCreated; });

    // the creation of the inner circle
    var innerG = svg.selectAll(".innerArc")
      .data(pie(data))
      .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "innerArc");

  innerG.append("path")
    .attr("d", innerArc)
    .style("fill", "grey");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to use the same data that generated the outside arcs to generate a full circle. Because pie(data) is two objects, you're creating two g.innerArc elements and just setting them to be the same color, i.e. grey, but that doesn't get around the edge problem, hence it looks a bit off. One hack would be to just make the stroke grey for both path elements.

```
innerG.append("path")
    .attr("d", innerArc)
    .style({"fill": "grey", "stroke" : "grey"});
```

However, it seems to me that the easiest thing to do is just to draw a circle. Seems unnecessary to use a pie chart layout to create a circle, when the circle element already exists.

```
var innerG = svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "innerArc")
      .append("circle")
      .attr("r", 40)
      .style("fill", "grey");
```